# Do MIME types REQUIRE the subtype to be specified

Tags: rss, mime-types, mime, atom-feed

The question is clear enough, but let me flesh it out with the actual example I am encountering:

In interpreting an RSS feed, there is an image specified sometimes where it is not known what *kind* of image it is, but it is nonetheless clear that the link type *is* an image, such as in this example:

```
<itunes:image href="http://static1.doda.com/57914/1500w/" />
```

That iTunes spec does not enter the image type attribute for the image. So then let's say I am taking this image link (with others) and re-syndicating it, but now as a standard ATOM link. To specify it *is* an image, the type attribute of the link needs to start with image (as an image MIME type), and yet what should I do about the subtype:

```
<link href="http://static1.doda.com/57914/1500w/" type="image" /> //??
```

I'm guessing MIME types can never do this, but is that the case? Can the subtype ever be left off? Another solution is not so happy either: to enter a FALSE but common subtype (e.g.: "image/jpeg").

**--- update ---**

Thanks to Julien for that research. So one solution just occurred to me: using a generic subtype of a given value such as: unknown, or none.

```
image/unknown

image/none
```

Maybe just go with 'unknown', but 'none' has it's benefits as well. This might be especially useful if a lot of people started using one (or both) of these values when they don't know the subtype.

I would love to hear in the comments how that idea strikes you guys, yea or nea? Good idea or bad?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/979135/is-there-a-generic-mime-type-for-all-image-files#comment1345233_979135 might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in theory, the [RFC4287](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) says:

> ## Whatever a media type is, it contains at least one slash
>
> atomMediaType = xsd:string { pattern = ".+/.+" }

Now, [from experience](https://superfeedr.com), there are many feeds out there which do not include the sub-type. [Be robust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle): if you publish a feed, make sure you include both... and if you consume feeds, be ready to handle feeds where it's missing!

Comment: You say "yes", presumably meaning that the subtype can theoretically be omitted, yet the example you provide appears to contradict this by stating that it must contain a slash. Does it instead mean that the slash does not require anything subsequently, like merely `application/`?